# How can I open doc and ppt files without any app installed in device in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, io, document

How can I open doc, ppt files without any app installed in device in Android?

I am  developing a document to go and I would like suggestions on how can I open doc, ppt, pdf file without any app installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a readable output for those files, you kinda need another app. To my knowledge, stock android doesnt have a way to read any of those files nativly.

if you can manage one app, kingston office i know personally can open those types(pdf is iffy)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng&hl=en

The other way i think is if you had an external interpreter that can make a web page out of it. Maybe using drive.google.com would serve for that, but i dont know how far the browser on your device can go with it.